# Error in loading particular model from tensorflow checkpoint

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have a tensorflow code in which I save and load models of a neural network.

```
def save(self, checkpoint_dir, step):
    model_name = "cyclegan.model"
    model_dir = "%s_%s" % (self.dataset_dir, self.image_size)
    checkpoint_dir = os.path.join(checkpoint_dir, model_dir)

    if not os.path.exists(checkpoint_dir):
        os.makedirs(checkpoint_dir)

    self.saver.save(self.sess,
                    os.path.join(checkpoint_dir, model_name),
                    global_step=step)

def load(self, checkpoint_dir):
    print(" [*] Reading checkpoint...")

    model_dir = "%s_%s" % (self.dataset_dir, self.image_size)
    checkpoint_dir = os.path.join(checkpoint_dir, model_dir)

    ckpt = tf.train.get_checkpoint_state(checkpoint_dir)
    if ckpt and ckpt.model_checkpoint_path:
        ckpt_name = os.path.basename(ckpt.model_checkpoint_path)
        # ckpt_name = 'cyclegan.model-2052002'
        self.saver.restore(self.sess, os.path.join(checkpoint_dir, ckpt_name))
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

I have a checkpoint directory having following files:

```
checkpoint
cyclegan.model-2052002.data-00000-of-00001
cyclegan.model-2052002.index
cyclegan.model-2052002.meta
cyclegan.model-2053002.data-00000-of-00001
cyclegan.model-2053002.index
cyclegan.model-2053002.meta
cyclegan.model-2054002.data-00000-of-00001
cyclegan.model-2054002.index
cyclegan.model-2054002.meta
cyclegan.model-2055002.data-00000-of-00001
cyclegan.model-2055002.index
cyclegan.model-2055002.meta
cyclegan.model-2056002.data-00000-of-00001
cyclegan.model-2056002.index
cyclegan.model-2056002.meta
```

If I call the load function I guess it loads the latest model. Please tell if am right or not. What I want to do is load a particular model from the above list. So is uncommenting the line where I assign value to ckpt_name would work or not? Or would it still load the latest model. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Uncommenting that line should load the specific checkpoint referenced. You can refer to [`tf.train.Saver.restore()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/Saver#restore).